# Network not showing up in the Chrome Extension Background Page on Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I feel really stupid but for some reason I cannot find the Network tab in my DevTools anymore... It's been there on the new Manifest v3 before, just somehow disappeared today for me and I can't seem to get it back. [This is how my DevTools look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oexmg.png), any idea how I can get the Network tab back?

[It shows in the regular Chrome Inspector just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M46n4.png) and in my other chrome extensions I have installed as well, I just can't seem to find it on mine for whatever reason.

Comment: It's a bug, see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/8XH_QsYK2nI

Comment: Awesome, didn't know that. Tysm!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the post's comments, it was indeed just a Chrome bug...

> https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/8XH_QsYK2nI